# earliest commonly used version of Python

Tags: python, version, backwards-compatibility

Is there an officially updated recommendation indicating which versions of Python should be supported by released modules?  Or perhaps a page giving a survey of production usage of various versions?  It's difficult to know how much use to make of newish features like context managers, class decorators, etc. when writing a module.

Note that learning which versions of Python are in common usage *now* is only part of my question; I'd like to find a resource which will provide up-to-date information for future readers of this thread (and myself).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not aware of any single resource keeping an up-to-date summary of production usage of different Python versions, but a good start would probably be to check which Python versions that are distributed with various Linux distributions.  Here's a sample for some of the most used server distributions (taken from [Distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/)):

#### Debian

- Debian 5.0 (2009-02-15): Python 2.5.2
- Debian 4.0 (2007-04-08): Python 2.4.4
- Debian 3.1 (2005-06-06): Python 2.3.5

#### Ubuntu

- Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (2010-04-29): Python 2.6.5
- Ubuntu 8.04 LTS (2008-04-24): Python 2.5.2

#### Red Hat Enterprise Linux

- RHEL 5.5 (2010-03-30): Python 2.4.3
- RHEL 4.8 (2009-05-19): Python 2.3.4
- RHEL 3.9 (2007-05-30): Python 2.2.3

Clearly, Red Hat is the limiting factor here.  The latest stable RHEL release ships with Python 2.4, and as there's a fair number of RHEL servers out there, you'll have to target Python 2.4 unless you want Red Hat users to install a newer Python version from source or from third-party RPMs.  If you don't mind leaving RHEL behind you could probably go for 2.5 or 2.6 instead.

Comment: +1: And in some RHEL distributions, building Python 2.7 from source is a pain because it has a lot of dependencies.

Comment: Helpful, thanks.  Is there a way to generate such a data view using distrowatch or another site, or did you compile this by hand?  I'm hoping for a convenient way to get an updated list in, say, a year's time.  ——————————— I also noticed that the date for RHEL 4.8 was typoed: the year should be 2009.

Comment: I looked it up manually at distrowatch.  It took only a few minutes, which I consider convenient enough since you probably only would have to check it perhaps every year or so.  Thanks for noticing the typo; it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) has 2.6.1 as the installed version.

IIRC, 10.5 (Leopard) has 2.5 as the installed version.